# 3d Models in WPF

Tags: wpf, chess, 3ds

My question is simply

1. How can I get a file with .3ds  or .obj extension loaded in a wpf project?
2. How can I drag and drop  that 3d model  with the mouse?

(I'm doing a 3d chess project)

Answer (score 1):

1. Blend has support for loading an obj file and converting it to xaml.  Unfortunately, there is no support for 3DS in the box - getting 3DS files requires 3rd party software such as [Reader3ds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement_members(VS.95).aspx).
2. You'll need to write your own hit testing, and handle this yourself.